# MySQL - can't see end of

Tags: mysql, installation, character-set

I am trying to pick the MySQL charset combination which is correct.

Unfortunately, at least on my screen, the list of options is very narrow and doesn't show the full text of the options.

I want to pick option utf8mb4_unicode_ci, but I literally can't see to the end of the option to know whether I'm picking the right option.

I guess I could maybe work it out by looking at a list of all possible options and then sorting them alphabetically, but this seems a very complicated way of doing it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it at the bottom of **alphabetically** sorted list.

But as you can't see the list very well, i posted an image.

So you see it is direct about `utf8mb4_vi`

I find your size of the window quite small.

[image: utf8mb4 collation]

Comment: Thanks.  It's weird - I tried expanding the window, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: that is why i posted the image, so that yu can find it. can you make the right sectionsmaller